# Multi Delete using checkbox

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, checkbox

I am learning Cakephp and I've been trying to delete multiple (checked) record  using checkbox, but still not success. here's my jQuery :

```
            var ids = [];
  $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(index){
   ids[index] = $(this).val();;
   alert(ids[index]);

  });

  //alert(ids);
  var formData = $(this).parents('form').serialize();


  $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "tickets/multi_delete",
         data:"id="+ids,
         success: function() {
     alert('Record has been delete');
    },
    error:  function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       alert(XMLHttpRequest);
       alert(textStatus);
       alert(errorThrown); 
             }
   });
```

and here is code in controller :

```
function multi_delete() {
  $delrec=$_GET['id'];
  //debuger::dump($del_rec);
  foreach ($delrec as $id) {

   $sql="DELETE FROM tickets where id=".$id;

   $this->Ticket->query($sql);
  }; 


 }
```

anybody will help me please. thank

Comment: you could try a .join(',') on the array of IDs and then an explode() on the server side to get the array of IDs passed to the script.

Comment: be careful - this looks like sql injections could really hurt you here. you shouldnt use the $_GET data without sanitizing it

Comment: Please use `$this->Ticket->deleteAll(array('id' => /* array of ids */))` to use the SQL injection prevention and abstraction Cake gives you. You *should not* write manual SQL, unless there's no other way to make Cake do what you want to do. http://book.cakephp.org/complete/1000/Models#Deleting-Data-1035

Comment: You're using POST in the AJAX call, and then _GET in PHP. Won't that cause problems? Or can you access POST variables from _GET?

Comment: I back what deceze said, plus for your AJAX call there's already a component in CakePHP with the Prototype library. A simple `$ajax->form()` creates everything you need.

Comment: Nicolas thank for advise, can u give me sample or link for the same case?

Answer (score 0):

you could try a .join(',') on the array of IDs and then an explode() on the server side to get the array of IDs passed to the script.

e.g.

```
var idStr = ids.join(',');
```

pass it (idStr) to the ajax call

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "tickets/multi_delete",
     data: {id:idStr},
    //more code cont.
```

on the server side:

```
$ids = explode(',',$_POST['ids']);
```

OR

check the jquery.param() function in the jquery docs. Apply and to the IDS array and then pass it to $.ajax({});

Note: You are using POST and not GET HTTP METHOD in the code you provided

Comment: Actually I have tried to explode $ids = explode(',',$_POST['ids']); but still not work. It always  reported succes but do nothing and data still in table database.

Comment: It seem the error is in data: {id:idStr}, Undefined index:  ids

Comment: Sorry,Undefined index:idStr in ticket/delete2

Answer (score 0):

use json encode and decode for serialized data transfer

Answer (score 0):

Since JSON encoding is not supported in jQuery by default, download the [JSON Plugin for jQuery](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/).

Your javascript then becomes:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "tickets/multi_delete",
     data: { records: $.toJSON(ids) },
     success: function() {
         alert('Records have been deleted.');
     },
});
```

In the **controller**:

```
var $components = array('RequestHandler');

function multi_delete() {
        if (!$this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
            die();
        }
        $records = $_POST['records'];
        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION,"5.2","<")) {
            require_once("./JSON.php"); //if php<5.2 need JSON class
            $json = new Services_JSON();//instantiate new json object
            $selectedRows = $json->decode(stripslashes($records));//decode the data from json format
        } else {
            $selectedRows = json_decode(stripslashes($records));//decode the data from json format
        }
        $this->Ticket->deleteAll(array('Ticket.id' => $selectedRows));
        $total = $this->Ticket->getAffectedRows();
        $success = ($total > 0) ? 'true' : 'false';
        $this->set(compact('success', 'total'));
    }
```

The RequestHandler component ensures that this is an AJAX request. This is optional.

The corresponding **view**:

```
<?php echo '({ "success": ' . $success . ', "total": ' . $total . '})'; ?>
```

Wish you luck!